# Can't use trig functions in eval syntax in Python

Tags: python, math, eval

Below is my code:

```
import math
x = eval("math.sin(x)", {'x':2})
print(x)
```

You know what I mean. It won't give my desired output. I just want to allow the user input a algebraic expression where x can is inserted also as input. The variable x will be substituted with the syntax {'x' :2} afterwards.

Comment: You're probably looking for `str.format` or maybe `str.replace` -- but using `eval` is not in general a great way to do this, since it allows the user to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: eval() is evil. Probably better to get specific operation requests from user input - e.g., "sin 2" and then parse that

Comment: Can you suggest other syntax that would help?

Comment: You overrode the default globals so `math` isn't available. `eval('math.sin(x)', globals(), {'x':2})` will work but is dangerous and probably unwise.

Comment: @Ronald Rosete. What the algebra formula look like?

Answer (score 0):

The [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) takes expression, global and local namespaces for the expression:

```py
eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)
```

With your call `eval("math.sin(x)", {'x': 2})` globals are overwritten, so `math` isn't available inside `eval`, only `x`.

As [@interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay) mentioned, passing default globals is dangerous. For your particular purpose I would eval like this

```py
import math

ans = eval('math.sin(x)', globals={'math': math}, locals={'x': 2})
print(ans)
```

I guess you are creating a kind of calculator. So, I would define a dictionary of all available functions first

- to not bother user typing each time `math`
- and to ensure which functions (names, generally) can be evaled.

```py
import math

available_functions = {
    'sin': math.sin,
    'cos': math.cos,
}

user_input = '2 * sin(x) * cos(x)'
x = 2

ans = eval(user_input, available_functions, {'x': x})
print(ans)

print(math.sin(2 * x))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `str.format` to include numeric values into strings. Refer to the documentation for more details on all the possibilities it opens:

- [Python official documentation: `str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```py
import math

x_str = input('x = ? ')
x = float(x_str)
y = math.sin(x)

print('sin({:.2f}) = {:.2f}'.format(x, y))
```

Output:

```
x = ? 1.05
sin(1.05) = 0.87
```

The `{:.2f}` syntax means I want to print a decimal number with exactly 2 digits after the decimal point. If you choose not to care about the number of digits then you can do this:

```py
print('sin({}) = {}'.format(x, y))

# OUTPUT
sin(1.05) = 0.867423225594017
```

Again, refer to the documentation, and experiment a bit, to see all the possibilities when formatting numbers into a string.

Comment: The question is about parsing and evaluating strings, not about formatting strings.

Comment: Hi @interjay . Thank you so much for your help. Apparently you have some mind-reading powers that allow you to know what the OP wants better than the OP and then tell me about it. That's awesome.

Comment: It's text reading, not mind reading. Such as the text "I just want to allow the user input a algebraic expression" in the question.

Comment: @interjay Look. It's simple: on the one hand, if the OP is dissatisfied with my answer, they can explain why in comments, using their own words. And then I would understand what they're dissatisfied about and I would be able to better help them. On the other hand, if you believe that the OP would be dissatisfied with my answer, and you try to tell me what you think the OP would think, then it doesn't help me help the OP at all, regardless of whether the OP is actually satisfied or not. So: thank you for trying to help. Have a good day.